# Serenity-BDD jsonPath validation

Tags: jsonpath, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm doing a serenity test and want to do some validation on json.
The json I got looks like

```json
{
    "devices": [
        {
            "deviceId": "0",
            "deviceName": "Device-0",
            "deviceStatus": "free",
            "claimer": "-",
            "claimedUntil": null
        },
        {
            "deviceId": "1",
            "deviceName": "Device-1",
            "deviceStatus": "free",
            "claimer": "-",
            "claimedUntil": null
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The order of the devices in this json is changing after I do some operations. I want to get a device by Id and want to validate the "claimer" and "deviceStatus".

My code look like:

```java
@Then("see if device with id {string} is status {string}")
public void checkIfDeviceIsClaimed(String deviceId, String status) {
    theActorInTheSpotlight().should(seeThatResponse("Get valid",
        res -> res.statusCode(200)
            .body("$.devices.?(@.deviceId == " + deviceId + ").claimer", equalTo(theActorInTheSpotlight().getName()))
            .body("$.devices.?(@.deviceId == " + deviceId + ").deviceStatus", equalTo(status))));
  }
```

And my error looks like

```java
Step failed
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: 'restAssuredJsonRootObject.$.devices.[' @ line 1, column 37.
   restAssuredJsonRootObject.$.devices.[?(@.deviceId == 0)].claimer
                                       ^
```

Is there any possibility to change the JsonPath Lib or to achive the right behaviour?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get result by using correct syntax.

```
.body("devices.find {it.deviceId == '" + deviceId + "'}.claimer", equalTo(theActorInTheSpotlight().getName()))
.body("devices.find {it.deviceId == '" + deviceId + "'}.deviceStatus", equalTo(status))));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works. I validated the jsonPath via online editor and it worked there. But I have no experience with groovy ;)

Comment: jsonPath, here, is jsonpath of Rest-Assured that based on Groovy Gpath syntax, not JsonPath you can found in some websites.